# What happens if a witch makes a veteran go on alert?

Tags: town-of-salem

In Town of Salem what happens if a witch causes a veteran to target themself, thus going on alert? The idea behind this would be that if you do it to a veteran they will waste an alert so they can't use it against the mafia or neutral killer(s) that you're teaming with. But since you visited them and made them go on alert it means that it would kill you, right? Do you die or do you live?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [ToS wiki page](https://town-of-salem.fandom.com/wiki/Attribute#Control_Immunity) veterans have "control immunity" so it is impossible for a witch to control them thus this scenario will never arise! If a witch happens to 'control' a veteran, the veteran will see the message "A witch tried to control you but you are immune".

Although if the veteran themselves went on alert and the witch tried to control them, the witch will die.

Because of these facts, it is never a good idea for a witch to intentionally control a veteran.

Comment: I've never experienced this myself. It's interesting how the devs thought of all of this!